# Wpf button with both result datatrigger storyboard and mouseover background

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm looking to implement this functionality: A button, bound to a command, that can signal back wether the command was successful in form of a red or green flash. At the same time, I want the button to look like other buttons.

This is the code I have now:

```
 <Button IsEnabled="{Binding EmptyingAllowed}" Content="Töm lista" Foreground="#555555" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="20" Width="65" Command="{Binding EmptyListCommand}" >
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#BBBBBB" Padding="1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Background="#DDDDDD">
                                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ClearedOk}" Value="Ok">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.01" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1" To="LawnGreen" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ClearedOk}" Value="Error">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation  AccelerationRatio="0.2" DecelerationRatio="0.01" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

When the command is executed, ClearedOk is set to "Ok" or "Error" and then to "Empty", this causes the flash I'm looking for, unfortunately, the usual mouseOver-effect is lost for some reason, and if I add a mouseOver-trigger, it always takes precedence over the flashing effect, meaning the flash is only visible of the button isn't mouseOver:ed.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: does this code works right now ? because I am not able to see any flash and all stuff

Comment: @MårtenThurén did you try setting `FillBehavior="Stop"` against `ColorAnimation`?

Comment: Dhaval, yes it does, are you setting the ClearedOk setting correctly? The way I'm doing it, I'm setting it to Ok then to Empty directly afterwards.

Comment: dkozl, that actually kind of worked! The effect I get is actually that my flashing color blends with the background mouseover color until the flashing color "peaks", so halfway through, if my colors are background: yellow and flash: red, I would get orange. Fortunately my mouseover color is a mild blue and my flashing colors are red and green so it looks sufficiently good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make datatemplate and model with properties of state and then binding in template to this properties.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
        <Grid >
            <Ellipse Stroke="White"
                     StrokeThickness="5"
                     Fill="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource CheckToColorConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this well enough to see how it fits into my solution.